# When was the last time China voted against the majority (51%) of the Global South during a UN resolution?

Tags: china, united-nations, global-south

> **China has again sought to portray itself as a responsible world power
> in its rivalry with the United States, and pledged to champion the
> Global South.**
>
> The latest effort came from top diplomat Wang Yi during a carefully
> choreographed press conference on the sidelines of the National
> People's Congress on Thursday.
>
> He said Beijing's diplomatic priorities this year were to "maintain
> stable relations with major powers, join hands with its neighbouring
> countries for progress, and strive for revitalisation with the Global
> South".

https://finance.yahoo.com/news/china-plays-unifying-theme-among-093000147.html?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAANu9l6sDG48tLNqore8kdNuvhRoT8y0F8gz3s0PvGXfR9KMJzwCinqIywmvyLMLKNDks8XCpzz075XwQc_AGiloxdO1iDHOhd4MVTMtw5r4vonYrKcVYilM-ZsPRp-5EcUXzawobqSBy3TYLGNpKi0_tZsmfjTpgyBpkWyY6Yg1N

When was the last time China voted against the majority (51%) of the Global South during a UN resolution? China likes to pictures itself as the champion of the Global South. Of course, this is what they claim and it doesn't necessarily mean the Global South also sees it that way. So I was wondering if China ever decided to vote against the majority of the Global South during a UN resolution.

Comment: This will be a hard Q because there's no site that tracks the votes of the Global South as a group. China is more likely to abstain in a situation like that https://www.brookings.edu/articles/figure-of-the-week-african-countries-votes-on-the-un-resolution-condemning-russias-invasion-of-ukraine/

Comment: VTC.  Can't do a 51% question using an undefined "Global South".  I know we get ritual objections to the term, and most of the time, those objection strike me as needlessly nitpicky - the term is "good enough" in most cases.  Not with an exact numerical criteria, as here.